# Procedure or function expects parameter which is not supplied

Tags: c#

I got an error when I try to update my record

> Procedure or function `(sp_UpdateEmp)` expects `(@dateofbirth)` parameter which is not supplied

Here is my function

```
public void Updatedata(Bussinessobject.BO EBAL)
{
  objconn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
  if (objconn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
  try
  {
    objconn.Open();
    objcommand = new SqlCommand("sp_UpdateEmp", objconn);
    objcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", EBAL.id);
    objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", EBAL.fname);
    objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", EBAL.lname);
    objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", EBAL.address);
    objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", EBAL.phone);
    objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", EBAL.birthdate);
    objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hiredate", EBAL.datehire);
    objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", EBAL.gender);

    objcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  catch
  {
    throw;
  }
}
```

Comment: My powers of psychic debugging tell me that instead of `"@birthdate"` you should use `"@dateofbirth"`

Comment: btw; a `try`/`catch` that only does a `throw` is adding nothing: you might as well remove all of those.

Comment: but what you absolutely **should** have is a `using` around that `objconn` - at the moment you are not closing the connection properly, and you will quickly fill the connection pool (there should *also* be a `using` around `objcommand`, but that one is only "bad", not "fatal")

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

Using SWeko's comment:

Replace this line:

```
objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", EBAL.birthdate);
```

with:

```
objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofbirth", EBAL.birthdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

- the parameter name has a typo (which can include case-sensitivity if the database is configured for that); if so: *fox the typo*
- the parameter value is `null` (which means it *doesn't get sent at all*); if so *replace with `DBNull.Value`*

Applying both possibilities together:

```
objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("dateofbirth",
    ((object)EBAL.birthdate)??DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter name in your sp is `@dateofbirth` and you are passing `@birthdate` from above code. So change it to `@dateofbirth`.